# Python cannot find module h2o

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, installation, h2o

I have Python 2 and 3 on Debian (via `apt`) and installed H2O following the [official instructions](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/1/index.html) (thereby using `pip3` instead of `pip` when executing the install commands).

Afterwards, Python seems fine:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
```

But when I try to use h2o, it fails:

```
>>> import h2o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h2o'
```

**What I've tried that so far – without solving the issue:**

- conda install h2o -> install OK (verified with "conda list")
- conda install h2o-py:

Error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - h2o-py -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
```

- Following this ["second" official install instructions](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html?highlight=module%20h2o#install-in-python) from h2o I found -> install without errors, but problem not resolved.
- Seems I now have many Python envs installed - not sure if this causes the problem:

Output of `whereis python`

```
python: 
/usr/bin/python3.6m 
/usr/bin/python3.5m 
/usr/bin/python3.6 
/usr/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python3.5 
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/lib/python3.6 
/usr/lib/python3.5 
/usr/lib/python2.6
/usr/lib/python2.7 
/etc/python3.6 /etc/python /etc/python3.5
/etc/python2.7 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6 
/usr/local/lib/python3.5
/usr/local/lib/python2.7 
/usr/include/python3.6m
/usr/include/python3.5m 
/usr/include/python2.7 
/usr/share/python
/home/mac/Apps/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m
/home/mac/Apps/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m-config
/home/mac/Apps/anaconda3/bin/python3.6
/home/mac/Apps/anaconda3/bin/python
/home/mac/Apps/anaconda3/bin/python3.6-config
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

**How can I let Python find h2o?** If this fix includes purging Python2, I am happy, just afraid of cutting dependencies.

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer below if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I use pip within conda and it works nicely:

```
$ source activate yourenv
$ which pip
```

- make sure it's the right pip
- go to www.h2o.ai/download
- choose latest stable release
- click "install in python"
- cut and paste the pip command

For example:

```
$ pip install http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/2/Python/h2o-3.14.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Now start python and import h2o.

Comment: I am using h2o3.20.0.5， so I changed the command as "pip install http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/2/Python/h2o-3.20.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl". But the link can't be reach. Only "h2o-3.14.0.2" can success, why?

Comment: This is the URL for 3.20.0.5.  https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wright/5/index.html -- and this is the pip for it:  pip install https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wright/5/Python/h2o-3.20.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl